# How do I recursively list all directories at a location, breadth-first?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

Breadth-first list is important, here. Also, limiting the depth searched would be nice.

```
$ find . -type d
/foo
/foo/subfoo
/foo/subfoo/subsub
/foo/subfoo/subsub/subsubsub
/bar
/bar/subbar

$ find . -type d -depth
/foo/subfoo/subsub/subsubsub
/foo/subfoo/subsub
/foo/subfoo
/foo
/bar/subbar
/bar

$ < what goes here? >
/foo
/bar
/foo/subfoo
/bar/subbar
/foo/subfoo/subsub
/foo/subfoo/subsub/subsubsub
```

I'd like to do this using a bash one-liner, if possible. If there were a javascript-shell, I'd imagine something like

```
bash("find . -type d").sort( function (x) x.findall(/\//g).length; )
```

Comment: Could you expand on this to include your language of choice, and the OS (Linux?)

Comment: Arg!  This is a "community wiki" question.  Annoying.

Comment: what makes this a community wiki question?

Comment: The asker checked the "community wiki"  box.  I think this is a case of: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/27839-hide-community-owned-wiki-for-new-users

Comment: Emil: good idea, tagged appropriately.

Comment: I wrote this which should meet your needs: https://github.com/tavianator/bfs

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `find` command supports `-printf` option which recognizes a lot of placeholders.

One such placeholder is `%d` which renders the depth of given path, relative to where `find` started.

Therefore you can use following simple one-liner:

```
find -type d -printf '%d\t%P\n' | sort -r -nk1 | cut -f2-
```

It is quite straightforward, and does not depend on heavy tooling like `perl`.

How it works:

- it internally generates list of files, each rendered as a two-field line
- the first field contains the depth, which is used for (reverse) numerical sorting, and then cut away
- resulting is simple file listing, one file per line, in the deepest-first order

Answer (score 24):

If you want to do it using standard tools, the following pipeline should work:

```
find . -type d | perl -lne 'print tr:/::, " $_"' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2
```

That is,

1. find and print all the directories here in depth first order
2. count the number of slashes in each directory and prepend it to the path
3. sort by depth (i.e., number of slashes)
4. extract just the path.

To limit the depth found, add the -maxdepth argument to the find command.

If you want the directories listed in the same order that find output them, use "sort -n -s" instead of "sort -n"; the "-s" flag stabilizes the sort (i.e., preserves input order among items that compare equally).

Comment: Add "2>/dev/null" to the find command, i.e.,
    find . -type d 2>/dev/null
Will ensure that find error don't screw up the results.

Comment: How about sorting alphabetically?

Comment: Does not work if dirnames have spaces. For instance, if a dir is "/data/Mundial/Trinidad\ y\ Tobago/" you will have just "/data/arbol/Mundial/Trinidad".

Comment: Thank you, this is the best one liner for sorting paths breadth-first that I've found (ignoring issues like spaces in pathnames).  If you need to sort depth-first, see this explanation for a sort callback with strcmp() on each path element, returning length1 - length2 if components all match (equivalent to treating nonexistent components as empty strings) https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820233/539149

Answer (score 7):

My feeling is that this is a better solution than previously mentioned ones.  It involves grep and such and a loop, but I find it works very well, specifically for cases where you want things line buffered and not the full find buffered.

It is more resource intensive because of:

- Lots of forking
- Lots of finds
- Each directory before the current depth is hit by find as many times as there is total depth to the file structure (this shouldn't be a problem if you have practically any amount of ram...)

This is good because:

- It uses bash and basic gnu tools
- It can be broken whenever you want (like you see what you were looking for fly by)
- It works per line and not per find, so subsequent commands don't have to wait for a find and a sort
- It works based on the actual file system separation, so if you have a directory with a slash in it, it won't be listed deeper than it is; if you have a different path separator configured, you still are fine.

```
#!/bin/bash 
depth=0

while find -mindepth $depth -maxdepth $depth | grep '.'
do
    depth=$((depth + 1))
done
```

You can also fit it onto one line fairly(?) easily:

```
depth=0; while find -mindepth $depth -maxdepth $depth | grep --color=never '.'; do depth=$((depth + 1)); done
```

But I prefer small scripts over typing...

Answer (score 7):

You can use find command,
find /path/to/dir -type d
So below example list of directories in current directory :

```
find . -type d
```

Comment: This is *not* breadth-first, as explained literally in the question.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you could do it using built-in utilities, since when traversing a directory hierarchy you almost always want a depth-first search, either top-down or bottom-up.  Here's a Python script that will give you a breadth-first search:

```
import os, sys

rootdir = sys.argv[1]
queue = [rootdir]

while queue:
    file = queue.pop(0)
    print(file)
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        queue.extend(os.path.join(file,x) for x in os.listdir(file))
```

**Edit:**

1. Using `os.path`-module instead of `os.stat`-function and `stat`-module.
2. Using `list.pop` and `list.extend` instead of `del` and `+=` operators.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find a way to do this with `find` but it doesn't appear to have anything like a `-breadth` option. Short of writing a patch for it, try the following shell incantation (for bash):

```
LIST="$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)";
while test -n "$LIST"; do
    for F in $LIST; do
        echo $F;
        test -d "$F" && NLIST="$NLIST $(find $F -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)";
    done;
    LIST=$NLIST;
    NLIST="";
done
```

I sort of stumbled upon this accidentally so I don't know if it works in general (I was testing it only on the specific directory structure you were asking about)

If you want to limit the depth, put a counter variable in the outer loop, like so (I'm also adding comments to this one):

```
# initialize the list of subdirectories being processed
LIST="$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)";
# initialize the depth counter to 0
let i=0;
# as long as there are more subdirectories to process and we haven't hit the max depth
while test "$i" -lt 2 -a -n "$LIST"; do
    # increment the depth counter
    let i++;
    # for each subdirectory in the current list
    for F in $LIST; do
        # print it
        echo $F;
        # double-check that it is indeed a directory, and if so
        # append its contents to the list for the next level
        test -d "$F" && NLIST="$NLIST $(find $F -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)";
    done;
    # set the current list equal to the next level's list
    LIST=$NLIST;
    # clear the next level's list
    NLIST="";
done
```

(replace the 2 in `-lt 2` with the depth)

Basically this implements the standard breadth-first search algorithm using `$LIST` and `$NLIST` as a queue of directory names. Here's the latter approach as a one-liner for easy copy-and-paste:

```
LIST="$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)"; let i=0; while test "$i" -lt 2 -a -n "$LIST"; do let i++; for F in $LIST; do echo $F; test -d "$F" && NLIST="$NLIST $(find $F -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)"; done; LIST=$NLIST; NLIST=""; done
```

Comment: Looking at it again, this definitely makes my list of "things that should never be done in Bash" ;-)

Comment: Can you also format it not as a one-liner to make understanding the code easier?  (But yes, don't do this in bash :-)

Comment: Also prints regular files in base directory.

Comment: The -1 option for ls is unnecessary -- ls automatically prints in one column if stdout is not a terminal (i.e. if it's a pipe).

Comment: k, fixed the regular file problem

Answer (score 2):

Without the deserved ordering:
    find -maxdepth  -type d

To get the deserved ordering, you have to do the recursion yourself, with this small shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
r () 
{
    let level=$3+1
    if [ $level -gt $4 ]; then return 0; fi
    cd "$1"
    for d in *; do
        if [ -d "$d" ]; then
            echo $2/$d
        fi;
    done
    for d in *; do
        if [ -d "$d" ]; then
            (r "$d" "$2/$d" $level $4)
        fi;
    done
}
r "$1" "$1" 0 "$2"
```

Then you can call this script with parameters base directory and depth.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but with the wrong ordering. I changed the question to clarify, thanks!

Comment: see my addition! I wasn't finished :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way, using find.  I've not thoroughly tested it, so user beware...

```
depth=0
output=$(find . -mindepth $depth -maxdepth $depth -type d | sort); 
until [[ ${#output} -eq 0 ]]; do 
  echo "$output"
  let depth=$depth+1
  output=$(find . -mindepth $depth -maxdepth $depth -type d | sort)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
find . -type d | 
  perl -lne'push @_, $_;
    print join $/,
      sort { 
        length $a <=> length $b || 
          $a cmp $b 
        } @_ if eof'
```