# GNU find: Search in current directory first

Tags: unix, directory, find, depth, directory-traversal

how can I tell find to look in the current folder first and then continue search in subfolders? I have the following:

```
$ find . -iname '.note'
folder/1/.note
folder/2/.note
folder/3/.note
folder/.note
```

What I want is this:

```
$ find . -iname '.note'
folder/.note
folder/1/.note
folder/2/.note
folder/3/.note
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Funny. GNU find on Linux gives me your first output, GNU find on Cygwin gives me your second. No idea on how to influence this; `-depth` should work but doesn't.

Comment: Same behavior here. `-depth` seems to have no effect.

Comment: @DevSolar, @larsmans: With this input, `-depth` happens to produce exactly the same result. `-depth` has no influence on whether files are processed before or after directories, it determines whether directories are processed before or after their contents.

Answer (score 3):

`find`'s algorithm is as follows:

- For each path given on the command line, let the current entry be that path, then:

  1. Match the current entry against the expression.
  2. If the current entry is a directory, then perform steps 1 and 2 for every entry in that directory, in an unspecified order.

With the `-depth` primary, steps 1 and 2 are executed in the opposite order.

What you're asking `find` to do is to consider files before directories in step 2. But `find` has no option to do that.

In your example, all names of matching files come before names of subdirectories in the same directory, so `find . -iname '.note' | sort` would work. But that obviously doesn't generalize well.

One way to process non-directories before directories is to run a `find` command to iterate over directories, and a separate command (possibly `find` again) to print matching files in that directory.

```
find -type d -exec print-matching-files-in {} \;
```

If you want to use a `find` expression to match files, here's a general structure for the second `find` command to iterate only over non-directories in the specified directory, non-recursively (GNU find required):

```
find -type d -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 \! -type d … \;
```

For example:

```
find -type d -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 \! -type d -iname '.note' \;
```

---

In zsh, you can write

```
print -l **/(#i).note(Od)
```

`**/` recurses into subdirectories; `(#i)` (a [globbing flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC84)) interprets what follows as a case-insensitive pattern, and `(Od)` (a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC87)) orders the outcome of recursive traversals so that files in a directory are considered before subdirectories. With `(Odon)`, the output is sorted lexicographically within the constraint laid out by `Od` (i.e. the primary sort criterion comes first).

Answer (score 1):

Workaround would be `find . -iname '.note' | sort -r`:

```
$ find . -iname '.note' | sort -r
folder/.note
folder/3/.note
folder/2/.note
folder/1/.note
```

But here, the output is just sorted in reverse order and that does not change find's behaviour.

Comment: In ASCII ordering, `.` comes before `1`, so your output is dependent on having a particular collating locale (`$LC_COLLATE`). Most collating locales in fact do have such an ordering, but not the basic locale (`C` or synonymously `POSIX`). This locale is often used in scripts to avoid with some applications that can't cope with an ordering that is incompatible with ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

For me with GNU find on Linux I get both orderings with different test runs.

Testcase:

```
rm -rf /tmp/depthtest ; mkdir -p /tmp/depthtest ; cd /tmp/depthtest ; for dir in 1 2 3 . ; do mkdir -p $dir ; touch $dir/.note ; done ; find . -iname '.note'
```

With this test I get the poster's first result. Note the ordering of `1 2 3 .`. If I alter this ordering to to `. 1 2 3`

```
rm -rf /tmp/depthtest ; mkdir -p /tmp/depthtest ; cd /tmp/depthtest ; for dir in . 1 2 3 ; do mkdir -p $dir ; touch $dir/.note ; done ; find . -iname '.note'
```

I get the poster's second result.

In either case adding -depth to find does nothing.

EDIT:

I wrote a perl oneliner to look in to this further:

```
perl -e 'opendir(DH,".") ; print join("\n", readdir(DH)),"\n" ; closedir(DH)'
```

And I ran this against /tmp/depthtest after running testcase 1 with these results:

```
.
..
1
2
3
.note
```

I ran it again after testcase 2 with these results:

```
.
..
.note
1
2
3
```

Which confirms that the results are in directory order.

The `-depth` option to find only controls whether e.g. `./1/.note` is processed before or after `./1/`, not whether `./.note` or .`/1/` is first, so the order of the results is purely based on directory order (which is mostly creation order).

It might be helpful to look at [How do I recursively list all directories at a location, breadth-first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539583/how-do-i-recursively-list-all-directories-at-a-location-breadth-first) to learn how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`find -s . -iname ".note"` doesn't help? or `find . -iname '.note'|sort` ?

Answer (score 0):

Find in the current folder

```
 find ./in_save/ -type f -maxdepth 1| more
```

==>73!