# Write a script that lists the content of a directory?

Tags: linux, shell

How can i write a script that lists the content of a directory and the sub directories on linux shell script ?

find ~/Desktop/Sample/ -type f -
Like that

Comment: Save `find ~/Desktop/Sample/ -type f` to a shell script file and run the shell script file.

Comment: should be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539583/how-do-i-recursively-list-all-directories-at-a-location-breadth-first)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recursively list all directories at a location, breadth-first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539583/how-do-i-recursively-list-all-directories-at-a-location-breadth-first)

Answer (score 0):

This line will create your script and will give it execution permissions:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash \nfind ~/Desktop/Sample/ -type f' > your_script.sh && chmod +x your_script.sh
```