# Bash find command not operating in depth-first-search

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I read that the `find` command in Bash should operate with DFS, but I don't see it happening.

My path tree:

```
- tests_ex22 
     - first 
         - middle
              - story2.txt
         - story1.txt
     - last
        - story3.txt
```

I run the following command:

```
find $1 -name "*.$2" -exec grep -wi $3 {} \;
```

And to my surprise, elements in "middle" are printed before elements in "first".

When `find` arrives in a new directory, I want it to look in the current dir before moving to a new dir. But, I do want it to move in a DFS way.

Why is this happening? How can I solve it? (ofc, I don't have to use `find`).

Comment: Could you please show the output you are getting and the output you want?

Answer (score 2):

`middle` *is* an element of `first`. It's not processing `middle` before elements in `first`; it's processing `middle` as part of the processing of `first`'s elements.

It sounds like you want `find` to sort entries and process all non-directory entries before directory entries. There is no such mode, I'm afraid. In general `find` processes directory entries in the order it finds them, which is fairly arbitrary. If it were to process them in a particular order—say, alphabetical, or files before subdirectories—it would be required to sort entries. `find` avoids that overhead. It does not sort entries, not even as an option.

This is in contrast to `ls`, which does indeed sort its output. `ls` is designed to be more of a human-friendly display tool whereas `find` is for scripting.

#### Sort by depth

If you're mainly printing file names you could induce `find` to print each entry's depth along with its path and then manually sort by depth. Something like this:

```
find "$1" -name "*.$2" -printf '%d\t%p\n' | sort -V | cut -f 2-
```

You'll have to adapt this to your use case. It's tricky to fit the `grep` in here.

#### Manual loop

Or you could write a recursive search by hand. Here are some starting points:

- [breadth-first option in the Linux `find` utility?](https://superuser.com/questions/194374/breadth-first-option-in-the-linux-find-utility)
- [How do I recursively list all directories at a location, breadth-first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539583/how-do-i-recursively-list-all-directories-at-a-location-breadth-first)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I could use `ls` in this case then?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some starting points. Let me know if you'd like me to expand on either of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows find operating in a depth first manner. If you want breadth first manner there's a tool that's compatible with find but breadth first that is called bfs.

https://github.com/tavianator/bfs